# Creating a clean unified border around an li and its ul with CSS

Tags: html, border

Within my `#header` `#nav`, I have a `<ul>` within an `<li>` that displays on `li:hover`. I want to put a border around everything but for some reason adding a border around the main `<li>` makes the `<ul>` within it fall out of alignment by one px on the left.

Here's a jsFiddle to show what I'm doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mh3Hg/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="thisli"><a href="#">Main Element</a>
        <ul id="children">
          <li><a href="#">First Child</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Second Child</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- end nav -->
</div>
```

The border that throws it off is the `border-left:1px solid #99B3FF` applied to `li#thisli`. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `ul` was always *inside* the `li`. The border is something which is supposed to be around the content, so it is theoretically around the inner `ul` as well. If you explicitly define the position of the inner `ul`:

```
#nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    z-index:100;
    left: 0px;
}
```

it is aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/Mh3Hg/4/